# Angular injecting custom data into services during with APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

I have a `ConfigFactory`. It's job is to retrieve app configs (external json file) and save in `ConfigService`.

**app.module**

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: configurationFactory,
        deps: [ConfigurationService],
        multi: true
    }
]
```

**Problem**: Another Angular Service requires the app configs information **in it's own constructor**. But configs information is *undefined* at this point of time (app initializer stage).

Now, I try to create an InjectionToken with `useValue = configs` so it can be `@Inject(TEST_DATA)` in `ServiceB`. However it doesn't seems to work.

**configurationFactory**

```
export const TEST_DATA = new InjectionToken<any>('TestData');

export function configurationFactory(configService: ConfigService): () => Promise<any> {
    return (): Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            http.get('externalPath').then((config) => {
                // save Config in configService
                return configService.saveConfig(config);
            }).then((config) => {
                // attempt save config. Example: config contains 'hello'
                resolve({ provide: TEST_DATA, useValue: config });
            }).catch(() => {
                reject();
            });
        });
    };
}
```

**Using TEST_DATA in `ServiceB` constructor**

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceB{

    constructor(@Inject(TEST_DATA) public data: any) {
        console.log('ServiceB', data); 
        // however this prints 'TEST_DATA'. Expected: 'hello'
    }
```

How can I allow another Service constructor to obtain data resolved by `APP_INITIALIZER/configurationFactory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Easiest would be to expose an observable from the `ConfigurationService` and consume it in `ServiceB`. Though this would need `ServiceB` to declare `ConfigurationService` as a dependency.

Now, once the configuration is loaded you can always emit it via the observable. Also you get better control on emitting desired value through the `ConfigurationService`